# How do I make my else execute in this scenario in python?

Tags: python

Right now only `if` and `elif` actually work and I know why but I don't know how to fix it. I tried a lot before this and I finally got to the point where it almost works, but I can't figure it out anymore. Its for a discord command if it helps.

Here's what I have, don't mind the stupid variables and things like that:

```py
    with open("lb.json","r+")as L:
      big_oof=json.loads(L.read())
      for loser in big_oof["losers"]:
        if loser["name"] == ctx.author.id:
          loser["addiction"]=+1
          print("if")
          break
        elif loser["name"] != ctx.author.id:
          print("elif")
          continue
        else:
          big_oof["losers"].append({"name":ctx.author.id,"addiction":1})
          print("else")
      print(big_oof)
      L.seek(0)
      L.truncate()
      json.dump(big_oof,L)
```

edit: thanks for the help! i have accepted the answer but my comments dont seem to be working for some reason, anyway, thanks again!

Comment: `if` and `elif` already cover all possible conditions here, wat type of conditions would you expect to be covered by `else`?

Comment: `loser["name"]` can either be equal to `ctx.author.id` or not equal to `ctx.author.id`, you have already covered both, remove `elif` as it looks redundant.

Comment: i want else to trigger when the user of this command is not in the big_oof yet

Comment: you can read the json file in python then treat the resulting json like a nest dictionary and manipulate the dictionary then print it.   Provide a sample of your json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait until the loop has finished to be sure that `ctx.authot.id` in not in the collection:

```py
with open("lb.json","r+")as L:
    big_oof=json.loads(L.read())
    found = False
    for loser in big_oof["losers"]:
        if loser["name"] == ctx.author.id:
          loser["addiction"] += 1
          found = True
          break
    if not found:
        big_oof["losers"].append({"name":ctx.author.id,"addiction":1})
    print(big_oof)
```

Comment: Ok, it looks like I missed the last three lines of your original code. Perhaps you could put those back in and see what happens.